# Python: saving a new file deleting all data outside a given range of time

Tags: python, datetime

i've a file like the following:

```
01/31/2021 08:51:41.222 5777 40.26
01/31/2021 08:51:41.441 5802 40.26
01/31/2021 08:51:41.644 5786 40.26
01/31/2021 08:51:41.847 5793 40.29
01/31/2021 08:51:42.050 5776 40.29
01/31/2021 08:51:42.269 5798 40.29
01/31/2021 08:51:42.456 5791 40.26
01/31/2021 08:51:42.660 5800 40.26
01/31/2021 08:51:42.878 5781 40.26
01/31/2021 08:51:43.081 5793 40.29
01/31/2021 08:51:43.300 5795 40.29
01/31/2021 08:51:43.519 5799 40.29
```

Named for example file.txt, i'm just interested in date and time and the third value; not interested with the last one. Like for example **01/31/2021 08:51:42.878 5781**. So i've a time and a value i'm interested with.
My aim is to select a range of time and save all the things in this range into a new file because i've a really long list in this first file, like datas from the whole day but i'm interested in something like 50 minutes.
Imagine from the given example i want only to save data at 8:51:42 and delete the other things. I want to have a new file with this lines in the end (to be honest the last value, the temperature, is not needed):

```
01/31/2021 08:51:42.269 5798 40.29
01/31/2021 08:51:42.456 5791 40.26
01/31/2021 08:51:42.660 5800 40.26
01/31/2021 08:51:42.878 5781 40.26
```

That's what i'm trying to code:

```
start = (input('Insert starting time for your range:'))
end = (input('Insert ending time for your range:'))

with open(r"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\file.txt", "r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    date = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]  
    hours = [line.split()[1] for line in lines]
    signal = [float(line.split()[2]) for line in lines]
    temperature = [float(line.split()[3]) for line in lines]

full_time = [d + h for d,h in zip(date, hours, start, end)]
datetime_object = [datetime.strptime(ft, '%d/%m/%Y%H:%M:%S.%f') for ft in full_time]
bad_time = ['start','end']
with open('file.txt') as oldfile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(    ):
            newfile.write(line)
```

I'm experiencing problem already when manually writing start and end date and time because there are problems while converting into the datetime_object.
But i'm also wondering how can i remove all the lines i'm not interested with and finally save my file. Infact there are missing stuff on this topic in the code, i was trying to find a solution but already got headache so I've decided to ask for help here instead of exploring pages with the search bar :p
All the help or external documentations would be appreciated.
I'm pretty a newbie with python, don't eat me please if possible :)

\ edit: What i want to do is: the user define start time and end time, then save lines from the files between start and end, delete the 4th value and write all into a new file.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean that you are asking the user for a start time and an end time and then getting the lines from the file which fit in the time block, then you are going to remove the fourth value and then write that in a new file, is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: You got the exact point! I'm sorry if i wasn't clear enough, i'm going to edit it now to be more clear, maybe it can help others. Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very much! I think user should write date and time like in the sample, maybe just without milliseconds. Something like this:   09/03/2021 20:00:00

Comment: got it, this is going to be an easy problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start = (input('Insert starting time for your range:'))
end = (input('Insert ending time for your range:'))



startDate, startTime = start.split(" ")
startMonth, startDay, startYear = startDate.split("/")


endDate, endTime = end.split(" ")
endMonth, endDay, endYear = endDate.split("/")


with open("a.txt", "r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    dates = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]  
    times = [line.split()[1] for line in lines]
    signals = [float(line.split()[2]) for line in lines]

final = []

for date, time, signal in zip(dates, times, signals):
    month, day, year = date.split("/")

    if startYear <= year <= endYear:
        if startMonth <= month <= endMonth:
            if startDay <= day <= endDay:
                if startTime <= time <= endTime:
                    final.append(f"{date} {time} {signal}")

print(final)

with open("z.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in final:
        print(line)
        f.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: Loving ya already, i'm going to try it and give you a feedback asap. Thank you very much.

Comment: you know you don't even need the datetime module, I am removing it

Comment: I have now removed the unused datetime module

Comment: Hello, i've tryed it right now and it's definitely working properly. Thank you very much again, you was totally helpful.